# Вопрос о CSS: зачем так явно указывать тип?

Tags: html, css

Я так понимаю, что в коде `input[type=text] {}` тип "текст" явно указывает на все input этой категории.. И только для них будет применяться этот селектор? Верно? И все это указывается в `[]` скобках?

Comment: Да, верно. Если вы хотите применить стиль к <input type="tetx"/> , то нужно писать как вы указали. https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно не писать input - достаточно [type="text"]. Это называется селектор по атрибуту: http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/selektory-atributov